# How to exclude configuration files from jar generated by gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have two projects:

- 1) common
- 2) app

app is a project that depends on common.

The project structure is:

```
project
    common 
         conf
         src
            java
            test
    app 
         conf
         src
            java 
            test
```

So in terms of build.gradle

common:

```
dependencies {
    ....
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
            exclude 'conf'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'conf'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test'
        }
    }
}
```

app:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    ....
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
            exclude 'conf'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'conf'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test'
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I check the **common.jar** generated in *build* folder when I run test cases of **app**. I can see that common.jar includes *.xml files of conf.

I also tried to add the following to common build.gradle:

```
jar { 
    exclude('conf/**') 
}
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to exclude conf/*xml from **common.jar** only when I run test cases of app ?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file, you can add the exclude command followed by the files that you want to exclude

```
jar {     
   exclude('your file name')     
}
```

Also if you want to exclude more than one file

```
jar { 
    exclude('file1', 'file2')
  }
```

Comment: @Guifan Li can you please try the above settings in your build.gradle file

Comment: I used jar { exclude('conf/**') } but doesn't seem to work.